# UITableView Sections Reposition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, xcode4

I have UITableView that have 7 section .. each section have 1 row .. My Question is :
**How can I move section from it position to another position** ?? .. like moving cells in TableView

Comment: you mean drag and drop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS 5.0, `UITableView` understands the [`moveSection:toSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW56) message.